# Doxygen Alias to Ignore Line

Tags: alias, doxygen

In an effort to adapt a company-wide header format to doxygen, I would like to create some custom tags that will be ignored by doxygen.  I think I can do this with an alias, but so far have only been able to replace tags with others.  What I am trying to accomplish:

/**
 * @company Company Name
**/

with an alias like @company="".  Unfortunately, this just prints the text with no section name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could use HTML style comments to hide parts, i.e.

```
/** Show this <!-- but hide this --> and show this again */
```

Or you could use @if...@endif

```
/** Show this @if VISIBILE but hide this @endif and show this again */
```

To save typing you could define a pair of aliases

```
ALIASES = hide="@if VISIBLE" endhide="@endif"
```

and then write

```
/** Show this @hide but hide this @endhide and show this again */
```